# How to pass OAuth token for Google SpreadSheet API from Kotlin code to JavaScript code?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to access Google SpreadSheet API in a special way, but I cannnot achieve that.

In short, I want to get OAuth access token in Kotlin code, but use it in JavaScript code.

At first, I get OAuth access token in Kotlin like below (using com.google.api-client.google-api-client and com.google.api-client.google-oauth-client-jetty).

```kotlin
        val scopes = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS)
        val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
        val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
        val inputStream = this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("credentials.json") ?: throw Exception("file not found")
        val clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            jsonFactory,
            InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        )
        val flow = GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
            .Builder(
                httpTransport,
                jsonFactory,
                clientSecrets,
                scopes
            )
            .setDataStoreFactory(FileDataStoreFactory(File("cache")))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build()
        val receiver = LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
            .setPort(8888)
            .build()
        val credential = AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver)
            .authorize("user")
        val info = Body(
            clientSecrets.installed.clientId, // clientId
            clientSecrets.installed.clientSecret, // clientSecret
            clientSecrets.installed.redirectUris, // redirectUris
            credential.accessToken, // apiAccessToken
            credential.refreshToken, // refreshToken
            scopes, // scopes
            "Bearer", // tokenType
            credential.expirationTimeMilliseconds, // expiryDate
            "Sample Sheet" // title
        )
```

Next, I want to use access token and access Google SpreadSheet API in JavaScript. I pass required information via HTTP from Kotlin code to JavaScript code. My JavaScript code like below (using googleapis@39.2.0).

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis'

// event.body equals 'info' object shown in Kotlin code
export async function handler(event, context) {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    body.clientId,
    body.clientSecret,
    body.redirectUris[0]
  )
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: body.apiAccessToken,
    refresh_token: body.refreshToken,
    scope: body.scopes.join(' '),
    token_type: body.tokenType,
    expiry_date: body.expiryDate
  })
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', oAuth2Client })
  const spreadSheetId = await createSheet(sheets, body.title)
  return {
    id: spreadSheetId
  }
}

async function createSheet(sheets, title) {
  const request = {
    resource: {
      property: {
        title: title
      }
    }
  }
  const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.create(request)
  return {
    id: response.data.spreadsheetId
  }
}
```

While I can successfully sign in via OAuth and get access token, I got a error below at `const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.create(request)`.

```js
{
  code: 401,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Login Required.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'required',
      location: 'Authorization',
      locationType: 'header'
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot understand why I got this error. So, my question is how can I successfully use Google SpreadSheet API in this case (authorize in Kotlin, use API in JavaScript).

Comment: Have you tried setting it into a cookie instead? After a cookie is set, it will be attached to every request the browser makes to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Do you mean that there is a way to set access token to cookie using 'googleapis' package? If so, I would appreciate it if you could show some example or documentation.